# Chromium fails when fidning semicolon in viewport

Tags: android, chromium

Our Android app embeds an online application for some functionality. The app uses two websites to carry out this functionality. The simplified version of the web view is as follows:

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IWebViewCallback {

    private WebView browser;

    private ImageButton backButton;
    private ImageButton homeButton;
    private ImageButton forwardButton;

    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("Qp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        url = sharedPref.getString("url", "");
        if (url.isEmpty()) {
            url = "https://10.10.9.200:8443/pay/";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            //editor.putString("url", "https://payment.kbzbank.com");
            editor.putString("url", url);
            editor.commit();
        }

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
        setMixedContentMode();
        browser.setWebViewClient(new QWebClient(this));

        if (isNetworkAvailable())
            browser.loadUrl(url);
        else
            browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

        backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        homeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
        forwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward);

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (browser.canGoBack()) {
                    if (isNetworkAvailable())
                        browser.goBack();
                    else
                        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                }
            }
        });

        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                browser.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

        forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (browser.canGoForward()) {
                    if (isNetworkAvailable())
                        browser.goForward();
                    else
                        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            if (resultCode == 200) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("Qp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    url = sharedPref.getString("url", "");
                    browser.loadUrl(url);
                } else {
                    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionError() {
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    private void setMixedContentMode() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            browser.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        }
    }
}
```

**WebClient**

```
public class QpWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    private IWebViewCallback callback;

    public QpWebClient(IWebViewCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("webview", "proceeding");
        handler.proceed();
        error.getCertificate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        Log.d("webview", "onReceivedError: " + error.toString());
        callback.connectionError();
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }
}
```

The web view is told to bypass SSL errors if they arise.

The web application redirects the user to another secure site for processing. The web view halts there.

The problem is semicolons in the web page. The following is logs generated by the embedded browser:

```
27493-27493/com.some.package I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "The value "yes;" for key "user-scalable" is invalid, and has been ignored.", source: https://some.site (1)
12-05 16:47:14.013 27493-27493/com.some.package I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.", source: https://some.site(1)
```

The cause of the problem is quite clear. The problem has been reported on [Android SDK's GitHub site](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/425). And websites should [commas not semicolons](http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/meta-viewport-syntax-comma-or-semi-colon/) for viewport.

Embedded browsers prior to Android 5.0 work (probably because they are webkit-based) but browsers in Android 5.0 upwards fail. The page also works on the Chrome browser that is downloaded from the Play Store.

The problem that we have is that the page that is failing is the login page for a third party portal and we cannot ask them to correct their page.

I would like to know if there are workarounds to bypass this problem.

Comment: Is this causing an issue other than logs? user-scalable=yes is the default so the fact that that's not being parsed should be ok. Alternatively, you could try to inject some script into the page that replaces the viewport <meta>.

Comment: Hi @DavidBokan. Yes. This is causing the page to fail to load.

Comment: How does it fail? A malformed viewport meta might cause the page to load with an unexpected layout width or pinch-zoom limits but it shouldn't cause failure in any other way and in your case, it seems the only thing that should be affected is whether the user can pinch-zoom or not. Perhaps there's a different problem. You should also ask the third party to fix this, this is a problem on the page even outside WebView that they should be interested in fixing.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem